# Restoring deleted open id references back to project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I removed by mistake few assemblies from my `mvc4` project, those which reference `membership access` using open id, etc.

Now I want to restore these references but I dont know where to find them, using nuget there are installed (tried to remove them and then install them again) but I cannot remove since it has child dependencies (tried all which appear on typing `DotNetOpenAuth.Core`).

It's sounds trivial but I already spend too much time finding workarround.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it manually you have to remove the old refrences from the directory in refrences than you can use this link 
http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

to download dll libraries and just reference them directly with browse select reference